# Deleting large amount of data from SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-delete

I am trying to purge large amounts of historical data from our database for any data older than 13 months.

I have written a stored procedure for truncation, however when I try to run them I have two problems.

Problem 1 - the deletion fills up the database transaction logs and crashes the database when the disk drives run out of space.

Problem 2 - The script itself takes a long time to execute.

Below are the statements in the SP:

```
DELETE FROM Header_Table WHERE Date_DT < @date
```

The `Header_Table` table has a `ON DELETE CASCADE` relationship with 10 other tables. That means when I fire the above query it deletes the data from the `Header_Table` table as well as from the 10 tables reference by `Header_Table`

1. And in the second statement, I am inserting the data from the `Information_Table` table to temp table.

   ```
   INSERT INTO Temp_Table (Key, AccNum, Exp, Name_VC) 
      SELECT  
         in.Key AS CRD_NFO_CIK, 
         in.Acct_Num AS CRD_NFO_ACC, 
         in.Exp AS CRD_NFO_EXP,
         in.Name_on_Card_VC AS CRD_NFO_NAME    
      FROM 
         Information_Table in
      LEFT OUTER JOIN 
         Card_T crd ON in.Key = crd.Card_Info_Key
      LEFT OUTER JOIN 
         Business_T business ON in.Key = business.CC_Info_Key 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN 
         Con_T contr ON in.Key = contr.Card_Info_Key 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN 
         Customer_Payment_T customer ON in.Key = customer.Card_Info_Key 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN 
         Temp_Table Temp ON in.Key = Temp.Key
      WHERE 
         Temp.Key IS NULL AND
         crd.Card_Info_Key IS NULL AND 
         business.CC_Info_Key IS NULL AND 
         contr.Card_Info_Key IS NULL AND
         customer.Card_Info_Key IS NULL
   ```
2. In the below statement, I am actually deleting the data from the Information_Table

   ```
    DELETE info  
    FROM Information_Table in    
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Card_T crd ON in.Key = crd.Card_Info_Key    
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Business_T business ON in.Key = business.CC_Info_Key     
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Con_T contr ON in.Key = contr.Card_Info_Key     
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Customer_Payment_T customer ON in.Key = customer.Card_Info_Key  
    WHERE 
       crd.Card_Info_Key IS NULL AND 
       business.CC_Info_Key IS NULL AND 
       contr.Card_Info_Key IS NULL AND
       customer.Card_Info_Key IS NULL
   ```

Comment: "The Header_Table table has a ON DELETE CASCADE relationship with 10 other tables." - This will *definitely* take a lot of time for any delete operation on that table. You may get more performance if you "manually" delete the (batches of) records from each of the tables one after another.

Comment: @HannoBinder Actully we are not aware of the further CASCADE'ing relationship for 10 tables. As this is clients production database, we cannot take much risk to delete table records manually.

Comment: Hmm, too bad. Considering the transaction log [this](http://databases.about.com/od/sqlserver/a/truncate_shrink.htm) may be helpful. - Deleting records in *batches* will be the way to go anyway, which also gives you control over how long the operation runs without interruption; you may want to make batches of, say, 4 weeks worth of data and delete one of these batches each night until you catch up with the table's growth. Don't forget to `commit` (at least) after each batch to release any locks and allow the transaction log to be shrunk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Such cases you should always delete data in chunks.What I suggest is,delete data in batches.

Comment: This looks good for not to grow the transaction log file but it will take same amount of time to execute these sql as before.

Comment: Yeah but its the safe and best way to achieve this.

Comment: I agree. Whenever I've had to do this I will delete chunks at a time. Use Delete Top # ...

As far as the transaction log filling up, there's no way around it that I know except to change the Recovery model from full to simple which I would strongly suggest against.

Just remember that the trans log is there so you can get the changes back. Your essentially working around that.

Could you at some point when the system is quiet change to simple mode, do the delete and then change back to full?

Answer (score 0):

How often are the transaction logs being backed up? If you delete in batches with each batch in it's own transaction, frequent transaction log backups should prevent the transaction log from filling up unless your system is not set up to back them up (or only does so on an inappropraitely long schedule). Note transaction log backups are entirely different from database backups and should happen frquently in a transactional system - ours are backed up every 15 minutes.  Also because you have cascading delets (which I personally would never have allowed), you will probaly need a fairly small batch.